# Error Creating AWS cloudfront with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create Cloudfront with s3 origin, There's something i don't understand and searching the internet did not help me.

So, When creating the cloudfront, according to this configuration (which is probably wrong)

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name              = var.domain_name
    origin_access_control_id = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control.default.id
    origin_id                = var.origin_bucket_id
  }
```

```
// output from s3/main.tf and passed to cloudfront, same as any other output variable need to be passed.

output "domain_name" {
    value = aws_s3_bucket.dreemz-video-streaming-source.bucket_regional_domain_name
}
```

Also tried

```
locals {
  s3_origin_id = "myS3Origin"
}
```

`origin_id                = local.s3_origin_id`

When `tf apply`, I see an error saying the origin_id can't be found.

```
creating CloudFront Distribution: NoSuchOrigin: One or more of your cache behavior target origins or origin groups do not exist.
│       status code: 404, request id: 332f412a-a432-4935-a0cd-f0fc6197658c
│ 
│   with module.cloudfront.aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution,
│   on modules/cloudfront/main.tf line 13, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution":
│   13: resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
```

One thing i suspect is permissions- so i read about this block:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.example.arn}/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.example.iam_arn]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json
}
```

which will grant permissions- But i don't understand.

The `aws_cloudfront_distribution` resource actually depends on the `aws_s3_bucket`,

When granting permission with `identifiers = [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.example.iam_arn]` im gonna need the `aws_cloudfront_distribution`, isn't it chicken and egg here?

So the question here is

1. According to the [official documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution#origin-arguments), it's supposed to be straight forward. am I missing anything?
2. If it is a permission issue, isn't it chicken and egg story as i said earlier?

Comment: *"One or more of your cache behavior target origins or origin groups do not exist"* - you cropped your `aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution` too early, the problem likely lies in `default_cache_behavior` / `ordered_cache_behavior` blocks.